# parsing wsdl to get xpath(node structure)

Tags: java, parsing, xpath, wsdl

I am trying to parse a .wsdl file to get XPath information. I tried wsdl4j but that does not seem to give 'type' information. Is there any parser available to parse and get XPath from WSDL.
Or  is there a way to parse complex wsdls which have elements referring to complex types and complex types, in turn, referring to elements
for eg

```
<xsd:element name="ContractAccountReceivablesPayablesDunningNoticeERPFault">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="standard" type="ExchangeFaultData"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="ExchangeFaultData">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="faultText" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="faultUrl" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="faultDetail" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ExchangeLogData"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The expected xpaths for this would be

> ContractAccountReceivablesPayablesDunningNoticeERPFault/standard/faultUrl
>   ContractAccountReceivablesPayablesDunningNoticeERPFault/standard/faultText
>   ContractAccountReceivablesPayablesDunningNoticeERPFault/standard/faultDetail

Comment: Hi, did you have the chance to try the answer below? Your feedback could be useful for my little project.

Answer (score 1):

Just created a [xml2xpath github project](https://github.com/mluis7/xml2xpath) with a bash script to generate XPaths from an XSD or XML file. If you just pass the wsdl to -x option, it will handle it as an XML file. The script will not extract the xsd files declared in the wsdl but you can download them and pass to the -d option one at a time.

`xml2xpath.sh -d test.xsd -f shiporder -t`

it will generate

```
/shiporder
/shiporder/orderperson
/shiporder/shipto
/shiporder/shipto/name
/shiporder/shipto/address
/shiporder/shipto/city
/shiporder/shipto/country
/shiporder/item
/shiporder/item/title
/shiporder/item/note
/shiporder/item/quantity
/shiporder/item/price
```

PS: I'm working on a HTML files XPath extractor.

`test.xsd` contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="shiporder">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="shipto">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: @charles-duffy I will appreciate your feedback on this answer.

Comment: Hi Luis Muñoz, Thanks for the response. I used a simple dom parser and was able to get the desired result, after which I did not check here.Will try and update the thread. Thanks again